# transform XML called by document function

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm calling in XML using document(). I need to transform the imported XML. Is this possible?

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('C:\my.xml')/*"/> 
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:apply-templates select="document('file:///c:/my.xml')/*"/>`, then you only need to add templates for the nodes in the file.

Comment: I added the apply-templates as shown, but I'm not getting the text from the document, just the tags.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you have, for instance if the root element of your `my.xml` is a `foo` element that you want to transform to a `bar` element then all you need is e.g. `<xsl:template match="foo"><bar><xsl:apply-templates/></bar></xsl:template>`.

Comment: I found my problem. One of my XSLTs was killing some of my nodes. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For example, a **my.xml** is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <a>XXX</a>
    <b>YYY</b>
</root>
```

and the current xml is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root_test>
    <test1>123</test1>
    <test2>456</test2>
</root_test>
```

when the following stylesheet is applied:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="root_test">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('my.xml')/*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[document('my.xml')]">
        <success><xsl:apply-templates/></success>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root_test>
    123
    456

    <success>XXX</success>
    YYY
</root_test>
```

notice that the templates for node `a` in **my.xml** has been applied.